# SpriteKit: Use one instance of a Class in multiple scenes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

Is it possible to make an instance of a class and then send/recive data from every scene in a game?

Ex: Let say you make a RPG game, and you want to create a "Party" with information like Party Leader, members etc... and then you want different battle scenes to use the data from the very same instance?

If possible, then how?

/Daniel

Answer (score 1):

First option: use a singleton.
Second option: pass the instance as a parameter to custom `init` method of a scene:

```
@interface GameScene1()
@property Party *party;
@end


@implementation GameScene1

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size party:(Party*)party {
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        self.party = party;
        .....
    }
}
@end
```